# About using a boolean array for memoization in a DP

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have a working recursive solution to a DP problem.  I wish to memoize it.

Currently it depends on two states: the index `i` and a boolean variable `true` or `false`.

Could someone please point out how I could memoize it?  Specifically, how I could initialize the memoization table (`dp`)?

I am confused because if I initialize the second state with `false`, I wouldn't be able to differentiate between the `false` that is due to initialization, versus the one where it is actually the value of the state.

Could someone please provide some advise?

Thanks.

To clarify further: This is how I declare the `dp` table right now:

> vector<vector < bool > > dp;

How do I initialize the inner `vector<bool>`?  I don't think I can set it to either `true` or `false` since I wouldn't be able to distinguish later if that is the *value* generated while executing (solving the problem) or the initialization value.

Edit: Adding the code:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    unordered_map<int, int> m1, m2;
    vector<int> n1, n2;
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    
    int helper(int i, bool parsingNums1) {
        if((parsingNums1 && i>=n1.size()) || (!parsingNums1 && i>=n2.size())) return v[i][parsingNums1]=0;
        if(v[i][parsingNums1]!=-1) return v[i][parsingNums1];
        
        int ans=0;
        
        if(parsingNums1) {
            //we are traversing path 1
            //see if we can switch to path 2
            if(m2.find(n1[i])!=m2.end())
                ans=n1[i] + helper(m2[n1[i]]+1, false);
            ans=max(ans, n1[i] + helper(i+1, true));
        }

        if(!parsingNums1) {
            //we are traversing path 2
            //see if we can switch to path 1
            if(m1.find(n2[i])!=m1.end())
                ans=n2[i] + helper(m1[n2[i]]+1, true);
            ans=max(ans, n2[i] + helper(i+1, false));
        }

        return v[i][parsingNums1]=ans;
    }
    
    int maxSum(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        for(int i=0; i<nums1.size(); i++)
            m1[nums1[i]]=i;
        for(int i=0; i<nums2.size(); i++)
            m2[nums2[i]]=i;
        n1=nums1;
        n2=nums2;
        v.resize((nums1.size()>nums2.size()?nums1.size()+1:nums2.size()+1), vector<int>(2,-1));
        
        return max(helper(0, true), helper(0, false))%(int)(1e9+7);
    }
};
```

I am solving this LeetCode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/get-the-maximum-score/

Comment: @YashShah, how should I memoize it?  For eg., if it was `vector<vector < int > > dp;`, I could have initialized the internal `vector<int>` with `-1`s, so I could just return if `dp[0][1] != -1`

Comment: Ok but instead of using bool you can use 0 for false and 1 for true... -1 for null.

Comment: @YashShah, hmm, so are you suggesting not using bool at all and instead using just a `int`?

Comment: Yes... like this vector<int> dp = {-1}; Am I correct?

Comment: Well, right now, I am using a `bool`; so if I understand you correctly, I think you are suggesting me to use an `int`.  So basically, `vector<vector<int>>` and initialize the internal `vector<int>` with `-1`s.  Isn't this what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes... You got it.

Comment: @YashShah, great!  Let me try it out.  I will keep you posted.  Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 easy methods for handling this.

1. Declare another `vector<vector < bool > > is_stored` which is initialised as 0 and when `dp[i][j]` is calculated, mark `is_stored[i][j]` as 1. So when you are checking wether the particular state is being memorized, you can look into the `is_stored`.
2. Use `vector< vector < int > >` instead of `vector< vector < bool > >` and initialise `-1` to every state to mark as not memorised.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to store values is using
`Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(); // just a java version`

then you can create key by appending i  & j and store respective boolean  value to that key. for example

`String key = i + ',' + j;`

// To validate if we calculated data before

`if(map.containsKeys(key)) return map.get(key);`

// To store/memoize values
`boolean result = someDPmethod(); map.put(key, result);`

Comment: Or simply we can use Boolean[]  (The object) array for memoization instead of boolean[] (primitive )array. Then the value will be null by dafault and once we get the value we can store the value true or false.
eg:
`Boolean[] mem = new Boolean[5];

mem[0] = false;

// Here mem[0] will be false and mem[1] will be null
`

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can use [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types).

> A nullable value type T? represents all values of its underlying value type T and an additional null value. For example, you can assign any of the following three values to a bool? variable: true, false, or null. An underlying value type T cannot be a nullable value type itself.

You can use null for indication of unvisited or unprocessed dp states.

you can simulate this in C++ by Initializing your dp memo to

```
vector<vector<bool*>> dp( m, vector<bool*>(n, nullptr) );
```

now you can use nullptr as an indicator for unprocessed dp states.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to overcome this problem in java, I find is to use the Boolean class 2D array, As the `Boolean[][] dp= new Boolean[n][m]`, is initialized with null, so there is no ambiguity related to the pre-initialized false value and updated false value.

hence it can be done as:

```
if(dp[i][j]!=null) return dp[i][j]
```

Hope this answers your question.